# How to analyse a number of tracks with multiple coordinates and classify the tracks as a whole with machine learning?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification

This is a small sample of the dataframe I am using:

```
    track                    time UTM_WGS84.Longitude UTM_WGS84.Latitude
1       1 2015-10-14 23:59:55.711            5.481687           51.43635
2       1 2015-10-14 23:59:55.717            5.481689           51.43635
3       1 2015-10-14 23:59:55.723            5.481689           51.43635
4       1 2015-10-14 23:59:55.730            5.481690           51.43635
5       1 2015-10-14 23:59:55.763            5.481691           51.43635
6       1 2015-10-14 23:59:55.804            5.481691           51.43635
7       1 2015-10-14 23:59:55.840            5.481692           51.43635
8       2 2015-10-14 23:59:55.882            5.481692           51.43635
9       2 2015-10-14 23:59:56.031            5.481693           51.43635
10      2 2015-10-14 23:59:56.041            5.481693           51.43635
11      2 2015-10-14 23:59:56.047            5.481693           51.43635
12      2 2015-10-14 23:59:56.053            5.481694           51.43635
13      3 2015-10-14 23:59:56.081            5.481695           51.43635
14      3 2015-10-14 23:59:56.121            5.481695           51.43635
15      3 2015-10-14 23:59:56.165            5.481695           51.43635
```

In the actual dataset, there are on average about 150 lines of coordinates per track.

I'm not very advanced in Machine Learning yet, and I have no idea where to begin for analysing this data.

The goal is to classify each track based on the walking pattern.  I need to classify it to something like potentially aggressive or not.

I want to do this with a few supervised learning methods in R, like k-Nearest Neighbor, Naive Bayes, Neural Network or Support Vector Machine.

Which method would be easiest to begin with? Can someone please show me an example or tell me how to deal with classifying this kind of data?

Comment: [not a bad place to begin](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021929004002258), the wikipedia main articles on gait and on machine learning could also be quite useful in illuminating the way from here on..

Comment: As a start:  You want to classify as "potentially aggressive" or "not potentially aggressive". How do you define that? Do you have a classified (by hand, say) training sample?  Other:  You seem to have a variable number of covariables/predictors per case. Most methods will assume that the number of precictors is the same for each case, so you need to define some (maybe many) summary staistics for the tracks, which can capture (aspects of) your concept of "aggressive/ Not aggressive".